# How to enable type hint for inherited Column class in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, type-hinting, mypy

While working with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy 2.0, I understood that the default field type is nullable. As I have many non-nullable fields, I did something like this:

```py
class NotNullColumn(Column):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, nullable=False)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Column
```

So it is easier for me to implement non-nullable fields. Although the logic works fine, I came to realize that type hinting fails for this class. I have installed SQLAlchemy with mypy, and I have the following model:

```py
class Notification(Base):
    __tablename__ = "core_notification"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    user_id: int = Column(ForeignKey("auth_user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    user: "User" = relationship("User", backref="notifications")

    message = Column(Text)
    sent_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    status = NotNullColumn(Boolean)
```

While the type of `message` or `sent_at` shows `Column[str]` and `Column[datetime]` respectively, the type for status shows `NotNullColumn` (without any type). Because of this, mypy complains when I try to assign a boolean to the `status` field, even though other fields work just fine.

P. S. I cannot manually write `status: bool = NotNullColumn(Boolean)`, as mypy complains again, because of the mismatch of types.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. If you are using 2.0, is there a reason why you are not using `Mapped` and `mapped_column`?

Comment: While creating fields? Well, because, this also does the trick. As I mentioned in the post, the type for normal `Column` objects is okay, and I do not have any problem with it. The problem arises when I use `NotNullColumn`. And I cannot manually type-hint as well, mypy complains.

Comment: I can't check right now, but does `_T = typing.TypeVar("_T"); class NotNullColumn(Column[_T]): ...` work if you copy the `__init__` signature from [original](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L1511) instead of generic `*args, **kwargs` catch-all? It should. Your class is not generic, so it'd be weird to have `NotNullableColumn[something]`.